# FAILED: using static functions with PHPmailer

Tags: php, function, static, phpmailer, sendmail

I want to use the static function for when i want the Mail class to run on several other pages and link to this one. The below code works as written (sends email successfully) UNTIL I add the "Class MAIL Public...(){" now it doesn't work.

Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong?

```
<?php 
require '../PHPMailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php';


 class Mail {

    public static function sendMail() {

 $mail = new PHPMailer;
 $mail->isSMTP();
 $mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';              
 $mail->SMTPAuth = true; 
  $mail->Username = 'memphis@gmail.com';                 
  $mail->Password = '******';                           
 $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';                            
 $mail->Port = 587;                                    
 $mail->setFrom('Urban@yahoo.com');
 $mail->addAddress('memphis@gmail.com');
 $mail->Subject = 'Test Mail 5';
  $mail->Body = 'This is Test Mail';

 if (!$mail->send()) {
  echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
    } else {
  echo "Message sent!";
  } 
    }
    }

  ?>
```

Comment: What happens when you try? Does it throw any errors? Where do you attempt to use the sendMail? As it stands, I do not see any obvious syntax errors, so more information would be helpful.

Comment: Nope it just a blank page and no email is sent or reviews. But if I take away the send mail function and just have it start with $= new Phpmailer then it works again

Comment: If it's a blank white page, check the server error logs for an error message. A blank page is usually hiding a generic 500 error, and the logs should give you more information.

Comment: It use to give the 500 code but after fixing all server side errors it worked. So I proceeded to the next step of added the static function and now no errors nor send. Just black page. When I remove the static function only then it works again

Comment: How are you calling the static function?

Comment: Mail::sendMail();

Comment: akshaypjoshi below got it. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Static functions should be called with Class Name.

If you are making a function `sendMail()` inside class `Mail`, then it must be accessed with `Mail::sendMail()`.

Consider the below example.

```
class Example
{
    public static function exampleFunction(){
        // Some Code Here
    }

    public function testFunction(){
        // Some Code Here
    }
}

// Accessing Non-static function
$exampleClass = new Example;
$exampleClass->testFunction();

// Accessing Static function
Example::exampleFunction();
```

Check use of [static](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.static.php) keyword in OOP.

Comment: I use the Mail::send mail() functions on the pages I want it accessed. Do I need to included it in the testing page also for it to work?

Comment: I just tried replacing the if statement at the end with Mail::send... and it still didnt help :(

Comment: No, you didn't need to change in the if statement. But you just need to call `sendMail()` function outside of class i.e. on the page you are testing.

Comment: Thank you that was it. I was missing the sendMail() on the testing page as it completely slipped my mind to re include the send function on the testing page as i do on the other pages. thanks.

Comment: Welcome. Thanks for appreciation.